# How to change the title of dialog at runtime?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog

I wanna change the title of the JQuery UI dialog in the `open` event.

I tried the following:

```
open: function (event, ui) {
    this.title = "new name";
}
```

but it didn't work and the title remained the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use the `option` method as described [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#method-option):

```
open: function (event, ui) {
    $(this).dialog("option","title","new name");
}
```

should work